# How to write a date & time shift query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please help me with writing a `CASE` query. Using the column name `PERFORM_DT_TM` - date & time format "MM-DD-YYYY HH-MI-SS"

Table name `PERFORM_RESULT`

The result I want is something like this:

```
BETWEEN'06:00:00'AND'14:29:59' THEN 'First Shift'
BETWEEN'14:30:00'AND'22:59:59' THEN 'Second Shift'
BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND'05:59:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
```

Comment: the column PERFORM_DT_TM is type date/time?

Comment: I hope that is a typo... HH-MM-SS should be HH-MI-SS, right? You don't show the month instead of minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for Oracle, and assuming that the `PERFORM_DT_TM` column is datatype `DATE`...

We can use the `TO_CHAR` function to format the time portion. For example:

```
TO_CHAR( t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI' )
```

And we can do string comparisons in a `CASE` expression. For example:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI') >= '06:00' 
          AND TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI')  < '14:30'
         THEN 'First Shift'
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI') >= '14:30'
          AND TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI')  < '23:00'
         THEN 'Second Shift'
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI') >= '23:00'
           OR TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI')  < '06:00'
         THEN 'Third Shift'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS which_shift
     , t.perform_dt_tm
     , ...
  FROM ... t
```

---

NOTE: This is based on the assumption that datatype of the column is `DATE`, and that this is for Oracle. If the column is a different datatype, then we'd need to adjust how the "time" portion is extracted.

The TO_CHAR function is specific to Oracle. If this is for a database other than Oracle, we would need to adjust the expression that extracts the time portion. (e.g. DATE_FORMAT for MySQL)

---

An equivalent result can be obtained more concisely:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24')     < '06:00'
         THEN 'Third Shift'
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24:MI')  < '14:30'
         THEN 'First Shift'
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24')     < '23:00'
         THEN 'Second Shift'
         WHEN TO_CHAR(t.perform_dt_tm,'HH24')     < '24:00'
         THEN 'Third Shift'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS which_shift
     , t.perform_dt_tm
     , ...
  FROM ... t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char(PERFORM_RESULT, 'HH24:MI')` to get the hours and minutes from the date; the seconds aren't needed for this.

For `23:00` to `05:59` you need to check two ranges, because `BETWEEN` doesn't know about clock wraparound, it's just doing a textual comparison.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '06:00' AND '14:29' THEN 'First Shift'
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '14:30' AND '22:59' THEN 'Second Shift'
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '23:00' AND '23:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') BETWEEN '00:00' AND '05:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END
```

You can also take advantage of the fact that cases are tested sequentially to simplify it, since you don't have to check the beginning of a range if that has been excluded by the previous case.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') <= '05:59' THEN 'Third Shift'    
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') <= '14:29' THEN 'First Shift'
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') <= '22:59' THEN 'Second Shift'
    WHEN to_char(PERFORM_DT_TM, 'HH24:MI') <= '23:59' THEN 'Third Shift'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END
```

Comment: @mathguy When you call `to_char`, that will return just `22:59`, the seconds will be discarded.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. I will delete my comment so it doesn't mislead others; I see someone already +1'ed my comment, even though it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PERFORM_DT_TM is in datetime datatype (as it should be), you don't need a format model like `'MM-DD-YYYY'` or similar; and you are best off using numeric comparisons rather than lexicographic.

The time of day is `PERFORM_DT_TM - trunc(PERFORM_DT_TM)`. `trunc` keeps the same date but truncates the time portion back to 00:00:00 AM, so the difference is just the time component of the datetime stored in `PERFORM_DT_TM`. However, this "time component" is expressed as a fraction of 1 day; to compare to hours, divide the hours by 24 (or alternatively, multiply the time differences by 24; I illustrate the first choice below).

Assuming your table name is `MY_TABLE`, your case expression can be written (using the "with clause" available in Oracle 11.1 and above) as follows:

```
with p as (
        select PERFORM_DT_TM - trunc(PERFORM_DT_TM) as PERF_TM [, other columns] 
        from MY_TABLE
     )
select [other columns, perhaps PERF_TM,]
       case
       when PERF_TM >=    6/24 and PERF_TM <  14.5/24 then "First Shift"
       when PERF_TM >= 14.5/24 and PERF_TM <    23/24 then "Second Shift"
       when PERF_TM <     6/24  or PERF_TM >=   23/24 then "Third Shift"
       else                                                "Error/Unknown"
       end as SHIFT
from p;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PERFORM_RESULT ( PERFORM_DT_TM DATE );

INSERT INTO PERFORM_RESULT
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-21 12:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-05-19 15:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - Comparing using fractions of a day**:

```
SELECT PERFORM_DT_TM,
       CASE WHEN time >= 6/24 AND time < 14.5/24  THEN 'First Shift'
            WHEN time >= 14.5/24 AND time < 23/24 THEN 'Second Shift'
                                                  ELSE 'Third Shift'
            END AS shift
FROM   (
  SELECT PERFORM_DT_TM,
         PERFORM_DT_TM - TRUNC( PERFORM_DT_TM ) AS time
  FROM   PERFORM_RESULT
);
```

**Query 2 - Comparing using intervals**:

```
SELECT PERFORM_DT_TM,
       CASE WHEN time >= INTERVAL  '6' HOUR
            AND  time <  INTERVAL '14' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
            THEN 'First Shift'
            WHEN time >= INTERVAL '14' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
            AND  time <  INTERVAL '23' HOUR
            THEN 'Second Shift'
            ELSE 'Third Shift'
            END AS shift
FROM   (
  SELECT PERFORM_DT_TM,
         NUMTODSINTERVAL( PERFORM_DT_TM - TRUNC( PERFORM_DT_TM ), 'DAY' ) AS time
  FROM   PERFORM_RESULT
);
```

*(or you could just convert all the times to minute intervals - i.e. `INTERVAL '360' MINUTE`, `INTERVAL '870' MINUTE` and `INTERVAL '1380' MINUTE` as the boundaries)*

**Output**:

*(Both output the same results)*

```
PERFORM_DT_TM       SHIFT      
------------------- ------------
2016-05-23 00:00:00 Third Shift  
2016-05-21 12:00:00 First Shift  
2016-05-19 15:00:00 Second Shift
```